# Setting value of the env variable with a shell script in a scripted pipeline

Tags: bash, jenkins, environment-variables, jenkins-pipeline

I have a **scripted** pipeline with one stage where I need to set the result of current build based on the output of a shell script. Unfortunately it looks that setting value with the shell script doesn't change the value of variable created using `withEnv`.

Is anyone able to pinpoint the mistake in the simplified snippet below (if there is one) or suggest some other solution?

```
stage('MyStage') {
    withEnv(["MY_VAR=null"]) {
        if (env.someCondition1 || env.someCondition2) {
            sh '''#!/bin/bash
            echo $MY_VAR              # null
            export MY_VAR="UNSTABLE"
            printenv | grep MY_VAR    # MY_VAR="UNSTABLE"
            '''
        }
        echo env.MY_VAR                   // null
        currentBuild.result = env.MY_VAR
        echo currentBuild.result          // FAILURE
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The environment of a child process is lost when the child process exits. So your changes in the child to `MY_VAR` are lost once your child `sh` process is done.

You will need to communicate the change upwards to your parent, maybe by using

```
echo $MY_VAR
```

and capturing that output in the parent. Alternatively, write the values to a file and read them in the parent.

Comment: `echo $MY_VAR` doesn't communicate the change upwards. Saving the value to a file is indeed one of the possible solutions but I was hoping that jenkins is somehow communicating back the values of the shared env variables

Comment: That's what I said in the second part, _and capturing that output in the parent_ :)